# How should one add axis-type labels to a table?

Tags: tables, labels

I have a table of plots of the following form:

[image]

It is made using code like this:

```
\begin{tabular}{r|ccc}
    & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \hline
    4 & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_4excl2excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_4excl3excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_4excl4excl.png} \\
    5 & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_5excl2excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_5excl3excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_5excl4incl.png} \\
    6 & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_6incl2excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_6incl3excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_6incl4incl.png} \\
\end{tabular}
```

I have attempted the following, but I think it's not a good way to do it because the spacings are disrupted and the lines look bad:

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{r|ccc}
    &   & ${b}$ tags & \\
    & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \hline
    4 & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_4excl2excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_4excl3excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_4excl4excl.png} \\
    number of jets 5 & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_5excl2excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_5excl3excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_5excl4incl.png} \\
    6 & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_6incl2excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_6incl3excl.png} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{PieCharts_HF/PieChart_6incl4incl.png} \\
\end{tabular}
```

What would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `\multirow`, I just overlapped the rotated label with the blank lines above and below.  I also had to use a smaller font to get it to fit.  The .748ex figure is precisely 1/2 the height of a number.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}% provides example images (when installed)

\newcommand\measureISpecification{4ex}% not defined in mwe
\newcommand{\ctab}[1]{\raisebox{\dimexpr \measureISpecification/2 -.748ex}{#1}}% vertically centers numbers

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rr|ccc}
   && \multicolumn{3}{c}{$b$ tags}\\
   && 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \hline 
   &&\\[-2ex]% provides gap below \hline
   & \ctab{4} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{example-image-b} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{example-image-c} \\
   \raisebox{\dimexpr \measureISpecification/2}[0pt][0pt]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\small number of jets}} & \ctab{5} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{example-image-b} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{example-image-c} \\
   & \ctab{6} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{example-image-a} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{example-image-b} & \includegraphics[height=\measureISpecification]{example-image-c}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular]